# flutter : How to get phone number of incoming call and SMS

Tags: dart, flutter

How do I get the phone number of an incoming call and SMS in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

am not sure there are plugins for these actions yet but you can use [PlatformChannels](https://flutter.io/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) to accomplish your task.

you can also checkout this [plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sms)